# Is there a DBMS that allows the "= NULL" syntax?

Tags: database-recommendation

Inspired by a StackOverflow question ([Why doesn't SQL support "= null" instead of "is null"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7078837/425809)).

Is there a DBMS that actually supports the `= NULL` syntax?

Comment: Why do you want this? I'd argue that the syntax is confusing to anyone who understands what NULL really means in the context of a database. SQL Server, for example, allows you to change the default behavior, but it WILL be deprecated and it can be misinterpreted by your co-workers (or break if their settings are default).

Comment: It's a question that popped into my mind from reading [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7078837/425809).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some implementations of SQL do recognise x = NULL as equality, the ISO/ANSI standard on the other hand does not. In SQL Server for instance, SET ANSI_NULLS OFF results in (NULL = NULL) = true.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
SELECT CASE WHEN NULL = NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SELECT CASE WHEN NULL = NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: Oh, beautiful.  That's what the ANSI_NULLS thing is for.  Nice.

Comment: The old sysbase style syntax is more readable in constructs like where x in (null, 1, 2) which you have to rewrite as where y is null or x in (1, 2). BTW even ANSI isn't stringent about NULL can't be equal to NULL. Just see how it handles GROUP BY. I really liked the old syntax, but I abounded fighting against ANSI defaults.

Comment: Be aware that the ANSI_NULLS OFF option changes the meaning of certain expressions. You can break or change the behaviour of your code just by changing the ANSI_NULLS option. Also certain SQL Server features are disabled when ANSI_NULLS is OFF. ANSI_NULLS OFF is a deprecated feature and really should be avoided unless it's essential for backawards compatibility reasons.

Comment: Note for MSSQL Server. **ANSI_NULLS OFF** is deprecated and in future version it ill be always **ON**. Any attempt to set it OFF ill raise an error. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You can configure Postgres to see `NULL=NULL` as true. See the documentation on [transform_null_equals](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-TRANSFORM-NULL-EQUALS) for more details. *End of Postgres specific part of the answer.*

I do not recommend to use this setting to make `NULL` equal another `NULL` since `NULL` has the meaning of being unknown. As you don't know if two unknown things refer to the same object (value), comparing `NULL` with something should always result in `NULL` (comparison result is unknown). It would have been better to call `NULL` differently – for example `UNKNOWN` – but SQL chose not to do so.

If you want to see if something is unknown use `thing is NULL`.

If you want to see if two things are equal or both are `NULL` use `thing1 is not distinct from thing2`. See the page end of [Postgre's comparison functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-comparison.html) for more information on this syntax. [Firebird's documentation on the matter](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-distinct.html) also includes a table which shows sample comparisons and their results. Wikipedia has [the tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Null_and_three-valued_logic_.283VL.29) as well. IBM's DB2 does also support the distinct predicate according to [their documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/sqlp/rbafynulls.htm).
Unfortunately, it looks like neither [Microsoft with SQL Server](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/286422/add-language-and-optimizer-support-for-iso-distinct-predicate) nor Oracle with MySQL do support it. For MySQL their is [a similar feature](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) written as `<=>`.

SQL 1999 defines a *distinct predicate* (*ISO/IEC 9075-2:1999 (E), section 8.13*) as follows (cases for array types not shown here, slightly reformatted due to this platform's restricted formatting support):

> i) ‘‘X IS DISTINCT FROM Y’’ is false if either:
>    1) X and Y are the null value, or
>    2) X = Y according to Subclause 8.2, ‘‘comparison predicate’’.
>   ii) Otherwise, ‘‘X IS DISTINCT FROM Y’’ is true.

So for the negated case `is not distinct from`:

- The comparison yields either `TRUE` or `FALSE`
- If both values are `NULL` it yields `TRUE`
- If one value is `NULL` it yields `FALSE`
- Otherwise it yields the result of first value`=`second value.

Comment: THis is especially important when using SQL generators where they do not know the nullability of the column

Answer (score 3):

You have to remember that NULL isn't a constant, but rather is an unknown.  You can't be equal to an unknown because you don't know the value of NULL.

Comment: I think it is more helpful to speak in terms of how `null` is treated than what `null` "is"

Answer (score 0):

There's a possible answer that 'all SQL DBMS support `= NULL`', but that is true in the SET clause of an UPDATE statement, not in a context that requires a conditional.  That context would not accept IS NULL of course (you could not write <s>SET SomeCol IS NULL</s>).

Comment: The question was more about the `= NULL` compared to `IS NULL`.  Setting a value to NULL is ANSI standard.  As you mention, all DBMSs allow that, but that's not what the question is about.

Comment: @Jonathan +1 for showing up just how inconsistent things are when it comes to `null` and because to my mind you answered the question "*Is there a DBMS that allows the "= NULL" syntax?*"